# How do I allow a user to login using Iframe on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I am using a login page from a separate website inside of an Iframe, so that the URL displays my site, and not the site within the Iframe. Users are able to login with Chrome and Firefox, but they are not able to login to Internet Explorer, unless I remove the iframe, and the user is forwarded to the other site directly. Is there any way for me to allow the user to use iframe with IE, so what they may login?

```html
<html>

<body>
  <iframe id="abc" frameBorder="0" style="margin-top:-14px;margin-left:-14px;margin-bottom:-14px;width:105%; height:110%; !important;padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;" src="https://test410.managebuilding.com/Manager/PublicPages/Login.aspx">
  </iframe>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are the users not able to login - or the iFrame is not displaying at all.

Comment: The user is unable to login, its as if IE has a block on it. Its not like that in any other browser. I am trying to figure out, do I need to add something to my code to prevent that block

Comment: Anything in the console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think IE 11 will remember cookies set inside of the iframe, at least if it's on a different domain. You'll either need to navigate to the site directly or use a popup window.

At the time of this writing, IE 11 and Edge in Windows 10 seemed to handle this differently, so you'll want to test there too. It seems to me that Edge and Win10 IE (sometimes?) treat the iframe as its own browser session for cookie purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
  <iframe id="abc" frameBorder="0" style="margin-top:-14px;margin-left:-14px;margin-bottom:-14px;width:105%; height:110% !important;padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;" src="https://test410.managebuilding.com/Manager/PublicPages/Login.aspx">
  </iframe>
</body>    
</html>
```

make   `height:110%; !important;` to `height:110% !important;` because there was the syntax error showing on that line and the iframe is showing the internet explorer

Comment: check if it is working or not in the internet explorer